# Soundcloud resolve on PHP

Tags: php, soundcloud

I'm trying to setup a simple app that should:

- get the client ID of an artist from its URL
- display the two latest tracks

However I'm not that practical with soundcloud and i just know basic php. I started to play with soundcloud but i wasn't able to handle it. A problem i have is that any code i write, it gets

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception' with message 'The requested URL responded with HTTP code 302.'`

The easiest setup come straight from the documentation and is an example to retrieve the comments from the track id, starting from a give URL.

```
<?php
require_once 'Services/Soundcloud.php';

// create a client object with your app credentials
$client = new Services_Soundcloud('my_client','my_secret');

// a permalink to a track
$track_url = 'https://url_to_a_track';

// resolve track URL into track resource
$track = json_decode($client->get('resolve', array('url' => $track_url), array('CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION', TRUE )));

// now that we have the track id, we can get a list of comments, for example
foreach (json_decode($client->get('tracks/' . $track->id . 'comments')) as $c)
print 'Someone said: ' . $c->body . ' at ' . $c->timestamp . "\n"; ?>
```

Just added (`'CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION', TRUE`) because I've read about it around the web... And I always get the fatal error... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve it. If the resources are public, then you don't need to authenticate. Here's the code that:

- Get user URL from a wordpress custom-field
- Retrieve ID from json object
- Retrieve the latest 2 tracks and display 2 embedded players

It just need your own Client ID you can get easily by registering on soundcloud developers section, and then substitute it to {Your_ID}

```
    // get user URL from Wordpress custom field
    $sc_url = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'sc_url', true);

    // if $sc_url is not empty, do
    if (!empty($sc_url)) {

    $unparsed_json = file_get_contents('https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url='.$sc_url.'&client_id={Your_ID}');

    $json_object = json_decode($unparsed_json);

    // retrieve the user ID from json_object
    $roster_id = $json_object->{'id'};

    // get last two tracks from the user and generate embed code for each tracks 
    $tracks_json = file_get_contents('http://api.soundcloud.com/users/'.$roster_id.'/tracks?client_id={Your_ID}&order=latest&limit=2&format=json');
    $tracks = json_decode($tracks_json);
    foreach ($tracks as $track){
    $trackID = $track->id;
    echo '<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F'.$trackID.'"></iframe>';
    }}
```

Hope it can help others :)

Answer (score 1):

'How can I use the soundcloud API resolve resource with PHP?'

- to use the *resolve* resource of the soundcloud API with php, following frafor's code, do:

  `$client->setCurlOptions(array(CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1));
  $response = json_decode($client->get('resolve',array('url' => $track_url)));`


  ?>

So first CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION and then the API call, your where almost there! :)
Hope it helps someone!

Cheers,
T

Answer (score 1):

the soundcloud servers have switched to secure and they now use https protocol for API / JSON as well.

My apps were not working any more so these are the other cURL options to get the JSON.
SSL verification must both be set to disable. I got it working only with this.

```
// Configuring curl options
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
);
```

Hope it helps.